# Angular2+ does not execute set function code on change if using two-way databinding

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm trying to share an object between two components.The parent component has the global instance of the object. The two children component get that instance via two-way databinding. However, when that instance changes, although changes are propagated, the set function associated to that field is not executed.

```
@Output() consultChanged = new EventEmitter<Consult>();
  @Input()
  set consult(consult: Consult) {
    console.log("Code to execute on change");
    this._consult = consult;
    this.consultChanged.emit(this._consult);
  }
```

Here is an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabmdk), where the console.log is not executed.

EDIT: The behavior that I'm looking for is to call the setters of all the components that share that variable when it changes (to refresh some other variables with the new values of that one). If you guys know how to do this differently I would also like to hear about it.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? With each click another 'C' gets pushed into the array and this list is shown in your components. That's what the current code does and it works. What is your aim?

Comment: Did you implement ngOnChanges to react to changes of the input?

Comment: @Marlaqk That won't help here because change detection will not catch mutations of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when that instance changes, although changes are propagated, the set function associated to that field is not executed.

That's because the setter isn't called when you mutate an object in-place. This isn't specific to Typescript or Angular, but just how setters work in Javascript.

If you want to make sure the setter is called, you need to treat the data as immutable. So instead of

```
this.consult.property = "new value";
```

you should use

```
this.consult = {...this.consult, property: "new value"};
```

Now the setter will be called because the *reference* itself has been changed.

Comment: I've just tried it and I get what you say. Now, the setter is called correctly on the component where I clicked, and the property also changes on that component. However, this breaks the two-way binding, as that change doesn't propagate back to its parent. I've just edited the question with more info about the behavior that I'm looking for.

Comment: For two way binding to work, the output of input x must be named xChange, not xChanged.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, didn't even noticed!

Comment: On a separate not, if you wanna share the same variable across many components, it might be a better idea to put this state into a service rather than passing it around everywhere. But this depends on the usecase.